# Using StringTokenizer to separate scalar variables from array variables?

Tags: java, arraylist, stringtokenizer

Given an expression such as "arrayA[arrayA[9]*(arrayA[3]+2)+1]-varx" I'm trying to separate the scalar variables (x) from the array variables (A), so I can store those values in two separate ArrayLists. I've never used StringTokenizer before so this is all I got so far.

```
//expr is the input String, defined previously in the code
Scanner sc = new Scanner(expr);

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        StringTokenizer temp = new StringTokenizer(expr); //I'm not sure what to use as delimiters
```

From here, if this much is even correct, I'm not sure where to go. Any help/pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Either you want to use a Scanner or a StringTokenizer - which is it?

Comment: If the array variables are all prefixed by "array" and the scalar variables by "var": where is the problem?

Comment: the only way to tell if it is an array is if it is followed by [ . For example, there could be an array varx[  ].

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the (deprecated) StringTokenizer is that you really don't have delimiters since you'll need the '[' for recognizing an array. (What else?) So I suggest to use a regular expression:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "([A-Za-z]\\w*)(\\[)?" );
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( expr );
while( mat.find() ){
    String fnd = mat.group( 1 );
    if( "[".equals( mat.group( 2 ) ) ){
        System.out.println( "array: " + fnd );
    } else {
        System.out.println( "scalar: " + fnd );
    }
```

The second group catches the '[' if it is there, so you know whether the contents of the first group is an array or a scalar.

**Edit** Being restricted to using StringTokenizer complicates matters considerably. You have to store a token (whatever is between delimiters) until a delimiter is seen. Then you can decide which list it belongs to. The expression using `?:` just selects the suitable List object.

```
String delims = "[]*+-/()0123456789";
String expr = "A[A[9]*(A[3]+2)+1]-x";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( expr, delims, true );
List<String> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> scalars = new ArrayList<>();
String last = null;
while( st.hasMoreTokens() ){
    String token = st.nextToken();
    if( last != null ){
        ("[".equals(token) ? arrays : scalars).add( last );
        last = null;
    } else if( delims.indexOf( token ) < 0 ){
        last = token;
    }
}
if( last != null ){
    scalars.add( last );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I either have to use StringTokenizer or another method that would not require any import statements.